# How to implement HTTPS base web service using SOAP in java

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, ssl, wsdl

I have implemented SOAP based web-service using HTTP and WSDL file. Now, I  want to convert existing web service to HTTPS based. As per requirement, I don't want install certificate in server side but want to encrypt message for secure channel.

1. How to convert existing WSDL file to comply with HTTPS protocol.
2. Is this possible to implement HTTPS without cert in server side.
3. For android client side using k-SOAP,Is there any requirement to install certificate from client side if server does not send
   certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [The SSL handshake](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.itame2.doc_5.1/ss7aumst18.htm) and [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). For enabling ssl, you should need to a server certificate. 
For configuring ssl on tomcat, refer to [Tomcat SSL Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). You can use client authentication if you need it. 
For client implementation, there's some different approaches. I use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).
Check out this great tutorial:  [Client HTTP Transport (including SSL support)](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html). 
Hope this helps.

Comment: here ,I want to generate cert using anonymous Diffie-Hellman algorithms that need no authentication.So how can i generate cert for server using DH.

Comment: Sorry! I don't have any useful experiences about using DH.

Answer (score 1):

You need a server certificate to use HTTPS.  It's how it works, there's no getting around it.  If you use client auth then the client will also need one.

You could instead encrypt your SOAP messages and send them over HTTP, but that's not HTTPS.

Comment: I don't need auth in HTTPS.So,if server side cert is needed than how to generate it using anonymous diffie helmen algorithms.So,client side there is no need of certificate.